# Show small popup on image hover

Tags: javascript, hover

Need to show additional info when hover the image, as avatars on stackoverflow.com. I would add an image to make it more clear, but lacks reputation. How to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

CSS:

```
#image:hover ~ #extra {
    display: block;
}
#extra {
    display: none;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="example_image.png" />
<div id="extra">Info for img.</div>
```

Comment: @user2121157 If this is not which you can start with, please post a comment about what you need, or add more information to your original post.